# fetch next last n element from table using my sql

Tags: mysql, group-by, limits

I have a table like this to track visits of my site hourly:

```
id  | year | month | day | hour | date          | visit
 1    1391    12      1     10     2012-11-10       15
...    ...    ...    ...   ...         ...              ...
```

I use this query to fetch last 7 days visitors amount.

```
SELECT Sum(visit), `day`, `month`, `year`, WEEKDAY(date) as wd 
FROM tablename GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 7;
```

Now my question is this: how can i fetch 7 days before this 7 days?

(the year,day,month is my local date format and i want to change it one time on registering)

Comment: Do you need to be able to handle voids in the data or can we assume that each interval will be 7 calendar days?  Put another way do we need to handle situations where you may limit 7 days, but it includes more than 7 calendar days due to voids?  Or do you want voids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `offset`:

```
SELECT Sum(visit), `day`, `month`, `year`, WEEKDAY(date) as wd 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 7 OFFSET 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the idea of using LIMIT here to get the last 7 days, I much prefer a WHERE clause.

I would change your query above to:

```
  SELECT SUM(visit), `day`, `month`, `year`, WEEKDAY(date) as wd 
    FROM tablename
   WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAYS
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Then to get the previous 7 days:

```
  SELECT SUM(visit), `day`, `month`, `year`, WEEKDAY(date) as wd 
    FROM tablename
   WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAYS AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAYS
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

I also don't like the idea of storing your local date format in the table.. you are duplicating data and it should be easy enough to convert the date when querying.